# mongodb extracting values from array

Tags: mongodb

Following is example of table in mongodb, I have multiple records for companies like this, which I need help with.
I wanted to query the below table wherein using value from company I should be able to retrieve the name of all the cars.

```
"vehicles" : [ 
        {
            "source" : "jeep",
            "tag" : [ 
                {
                    "company" : "toyota",
                    "name" : "fortuner"
                },
                {
                    "company" : "rangerover",
                    "name" : "discovery"
            ]
        }
]
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
db.vehicles.find({tag: {$elemMatch: {company:'toyota'}}}).pretty();
```

read more here : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Comment: thanks for your reply, could you help me with multiple records, I have updated the table... Thanks...